# How are string paths used in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, windows-subsystem-for-linux, androidx

*Context: I want to migrate an Android project to AndroidX. There's a tool in Android Studio to automatize this that doesn't work really well. [This is documentated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54511777/cannot-migrate-to-androidx) and I've found a script to replace all references in the project with a text file to map them.*

I want to run a bash script in Windows. I'm using Ubuntu TLS with the property configuration enabled in Windows. The script is:

```
MAPPING_FILE=C:\Users\name\Desktop\androidx-class-mapping.csv
PROJECT_DIR=C:\Proyectos\Proyecto STH trunk

replace=""
while IFS=, read -r from to
do
    replace+="; s/$from/$to/g"
done <<< "$(cat $MAPPING_FILE)"

find $PROJECT_DIR \( -name "*.kt" -o -name "*.java" -o -name "*.xml" \) -type f -not -path '*/\.git*' -print0 | xargs -0 gsed -i "$replace"
```

When I run the script in bash I get:

```
./script.sh: line 15: STH: command not found
cat: 'C:/Users/aperez/Desktop/androidx-class-mapping.csv': No such file or directory
xargs: gsed: No such file or directory
```

I'm not really into Linux systems, but I remember something about string with blanks. I've tried quotations on paths ("C:\...") to avoid it to be interpreted as a command, but doesn't work. About the second line error: the file does exist in that path. I can't recognize the third error.
I've searched about strings usage in bash but I can't make it works, I will appreciate some help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First error: double-quote the parameter expansion to avoid word splitting at spaces:

```sh
find "$PROJECT_DIR" ...
```

Second error: I am surprised that you got this error. It should have been:

```
cat: 'C:UsersaperezDesktopandroidx-class-mapping.csv': No such file or directory
```

because the backslashes in your `MAPPING_FILE` assignment should have been discarded. Use single-quotes to preserve the backslashes:

```sh
MAPPING_FILE='C:\Users\name\Desktop\androidx-class-mapping.csv'
```

The same applies to the `PROJECT_DIR` assignment; single-quote it:

```sh
PROJECT_DIR='C:\Proyectos\Proyecto STH trunk'
```

And replace `done <<< "$(cat $MAPPING_FILE)"` by `done < "$MAPPING_FILE"`. Using cat to redirect a file content to another command is frequently an anti-pattern.

Third error: `gsed` is not installed, or its name is not `gsed` but `sed`, or its directory is not in your `PATH`. Install `gsed` (or `sed`) if it is not already installed, set your `PATH` environment variable, and use the right command name:

```sh
$ export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/gsed-or-sed/directory
$ (g)sed --version
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have a Windows Subsystem for Linux, and the link between both is made using a Linux mounting point, as you can see from following commands:

```
WSL Prompt>/mnt/c/Temp_Folder/a$ df -k
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
...
C:\            999036924 491402636 507634288  50% /mnt/c

WSL Prompt>/mnt/c/Temp_Folder/a$ sudo mount -v
...
C:\ on /mnt/c type drvfs (rw,noatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,case=off)
```

So, if you want to work on your computer, based on your WSL, you might need to replace `C:\` by `/mnt/c/` (and don't forget to use slashes instead of backslashes).